# How to improve the sentiment score if I am using vader in NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

I am working with social media data. I am getting almost a neutral score for positive sentences too and code is not understanding the statement rather just classifying using the corpus.

1. Is there any way to improve this sentiment score ?People have suggested to use compound score but it is not helping much
2. Any other work around to add our own corpus and use it in vader . I mean i dont want to add words manually , is there any social media corpus with predefined sentiments  ?
3. Any other model/way altogether to use for data without labels ?

Answer (score 2):

Vader is already quite sophisticated in terms of its workings, it takes into account negation words, and is specialised to social-media snippets (you'll notice it has things like smileys included in its lexicon). Vader, however, will not be able to capture the subtle nuances within language, as essentially it is just an advanced bag-of-words model. [This](https://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/10.1108/JCM-03-2017-2141) article discusses the limitations of lexicon's versus machine-learning based methods more comprehensivley.

You could try adding in other lexica to see if that improves results, however as vader is already trained in your domain I'm not sure how succesful that will be. My suggestion would be to examine snippets that are misclassified, and determine if adding a small list of extra words would be enough to increase your accuracy.

However, don't worry if you're getting low-ish accuracy using the lexicon-based approach, thats simply due to the tradeoff between not having to manually label your data to make it suitable for machine learning, and the extra increase in accuracy that machine-learning can often yield.